# Google auth endpoint redirects to a 400 Error page

Tags: google-oauth

Recently, my app's google signin stopped working by throwing 400 Error. We were earlier using the old oauth endpoints and I updated to the new `v2` endpoints for auth/token and it doesn't seem to help as well.

Upon sending the Auth request (using WS url in Scala) with the required parameters, the ahc response gives back the following URL to redirect to

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fsignin%2Foauth%2Flegacy%2Fconsent%3Fauthuser%3Dunknown%26XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.......

Instead of taking to the prompt screen to login the above url redirects to this 400 error page

https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/legacy/consent?authuser=0&part=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX......

Any insights on this is much appreciated!

Thanks,
Baskaran

Comment: cc/ Google Identity Team - @nvnagr

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help, you, but I've had something like that in this [bug issue discussion](https://github.com/keeweb/keeweb/issues/1499), that lead me to this same https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/legacy/consent URL.

TL;DR: A MITM is using/destroying your request.

The application tried to open a link to Google Auth, the desktop captured the link and either mangled the data or did a preflight on that one-time URL, which expired it, and then it opened the browser.

See if something between you and the web is "proxying" your requests the wrong way.